# Email Content only showing the HTML tags

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, jmail

I created a script that sends an email to the user when they register.

The email code is:

```
$return = JFactory::getMailer()->sendMail($data['mailfrom'], $data['fromname'], $data['email'], $emailSubject, $emailBody,1);
```

But the result is:

```
 <p>&lt;html&gt;<br />&lt;head&gt;<br />&lt;/head&gt;<br />&lt;body&gt;<br />testing<br />&lt;/body&gt;<br />&lt;/html&gt;</p>
```

What's required for the correct output?

Comment: have you tried using `->html(false)`?

Comment: @lodder5 ,only used  true

Comment: i get data from xml form field , an editor field, is it the error?

Comment: No No, I mean try using `JFactory::getMailer()->html(false)->sendMail(...);`

Comment: it seems ,Call to undefined method JMail::html() error

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, try this: `JFactory::getMailer()->isHTML(false)->sendMail($data['mailfrom'], $data['fromname'], $data['email'], $emailSubject, $emailBody,1);`

Comment: again same result ,<html>
<head></head><body>testing</body></html>

Comment: Are you getting the text from editor input? From a form or something like that. That looks like something an editor would produce if you tried to enter the code in wysiwyg mode.

Comment: yes ,i am getting input from editor , i already choose the editor-none, but the email content only showing the html tags

Comment: finally i got the output, using $htmcontent=html_entity_decode($params->get('editor'),ENT_QUOTES);

Answer (score 2):

You just need to decode the entities before passing it to the email.

Something like:

```
$html = html_entity_decode($emailBody);
```

or better still

```
$html = html_entity_decode($emailBody, ENT_QUOTES);
```